# Как считать строку с пробелами в цикле while через `getline()?

Tags: c++, строки, циклы

Нужно считать строку с пробелами в цикле `while`. Делаю это через `getline(cin, string);` и при первом вхождении в цикл все ОК, но при следующих не читает строку, а сама строка соответственно становится пустой и программа не работает.

Код примерно следующий:

```
bool next = true;
while (next)
{
    cout << endl << "Введите команду:" << endl;
    getline(cin, read_comand, '\n');

. . .

cout << "Продолжить? 1 - да, 0 - нет" << endl;
    next = check();
}
```

Внутри функционал который не важен. важно что при втором заходе в цикл и всех последующих не читает строку а автоматично устанавливает ее пустой и программа переходит в конец цикла, где спрашивает о продолжении.

Как поправить, чтоб при каждом проходе цикла читалась нужная строка?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: попробуйте `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` перед `getline()`. Полный (но минимальный) примера кода и соответствующего ввода/вывода, которые проблему показывают, могли бы помочь локализовать проблему

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите такой вариант (если не 0 продолжаем даже если не 1)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits.h>

bool check()
{
    char answ[2] = "";
    std::cout << "Продолжить? 1 - да, 0 - нет" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get( answ, 2 );
    std::cin.ignore( INT_MAX, '\n' );
    if( answ[0] == '0' )
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale ( LC_CTYPE , "Russian");
    bool next = true;
    std::string read_comand;
    while (next)
    {
        std::cout << "Введите команду и нажмите Enter:";
        getline(std::cin, read_comand, '\n');
        std::cout << "Введено: " << read_comand << std::endl;
//. . .

        next = check();
    }

    std::cout << "До свидания";

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Вывод:]